# Why does there appear to be a ן (final nun) in the middle of a word (שןיתי), is it a typo or what?

Tags: hebrew, spelling-variants

I am working from a scanned document. There are vavs, nuns, and final nuns in the text, but there appears also to be a final nun mid word.

[image: scan of text, presumed to be Psalms 16:8-9]

It makes sense if this were a vav, as it would then read as:

> שִׁוִּיתִי יְהֹוָה לְנֶגְדִּי תָמִיד כִּי מִימִינִי בַּל־אֶמּוֹט
>
> לָכֵן  שָׂמַח לִבִּי וַיָּגֶל כְּבוֹדִי אַף־בְּשָׂרִי יִשְׁכֹּן
> לָבֶטַח

which is from Tehillim (Psalms) 16:8-9.

Is it a typo for a vav (שִׁוִּיתִי), nun (שניתי), or what could be an explanation?

Comment: And [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full verse reads *Shiviti* with a *yud* and a *vav* as can be seen [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.16.8?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> **שִׁוִּ֬יתִי** יְהֹוָ֣ה לְנֶגְדִּ֣י תָמִ֑יד כִּ֥י מִֽ֝ימִינִ֗י
> בַּל־אֶמּֽוֹט׃

Must be a scanning issue

Comment: I can confirm that. It looks like they scanned the Sim Shalom Siddur 1985, but tried to OCR and re-typeset only that page.